# U-Net with Pre-Trained ResNet throws dimension error must match

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have an RGB image of mask for Segmentation of dimensions 900x600 (width, height)
My U-Net code is the ff. I do not really want to resize the output too much it is fine if it is resized without losing much of the aspect ratio.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import models

def convrelu(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding):
  return nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding=padding),
      nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
  )

class ResNetUNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_class=1):
    super().__init__()

    self.base_model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    self.base_layers = list(self.base_model.children())

    self.layer0 = nn.Sequential(*self.base_layers[:3]) # size=(N, 64, x.H/2, x.W/2)
    self.layer0_1x1 = convrelu(64, 64, 1, 0)
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(*self.base_layers[3:5]) # size=(N, 64, x.H/4, x.W/4)
    self.layer1_1x1 = convrelu(64, 64, 1, 0)
    self.layer2 = self.base_layers[5]  # size=(N, 128, x.H/8, x.W/8)
    self.layer2_1x1 = convrelu(128, 128, 1, 0)
    self.layer3 = self.base_layers[6]  # size=(N, 256, x.H/16, x.W/16)
    self.layer3_1x1 = convrelu(256, 256, 1, 0)
    self.layer4 = self.base_layers[7]  # size=(N, 512, x.H/32, x.W/32)
    self.layer4_1x1 = convrelu(512, 512, 1, 0)

    self.upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)

    self.conv_up3 = convrelu(256 + 512, 512, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up2 = convrelu(128 + 512, 256, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up1 = convrelu(64 + 256, 256, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up0 = convrelu(64 + 256, 128, 3, 1)

    self.conv_original_size0 = convrelu(3, 64, 3, 1)
    self.conv_original_size1 = convrelu(64, 64, 3, 1)
    self.conv_original_size2 = convrelu(64 + 128, 64, 3, 1)

    self.conv_last = nn.Conv2d(64, n_class, 1)

  def forward(self, input):
    x_original = self.conv_original_size0(input)
    x_original = self.conv_original_size1(x_original)

    layer0 = self.layer0(input)
    layer1 = self.layer1(layer0)
    layer2 = self.layer2(layer1)
    layer3 = self.layer3(layer2)
    layer4 = self.layer4(layer3)

    layer4 = self.layer4_1x1(layer4)
    x = self.upsample(layer4)
    layer3 = self.layer3_1x1(layer3)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer3], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up3(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer2 = self.layer2_1x1(layer2)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer2], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up2(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer1 = self.layer1_1x1(layer1)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer1], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up1(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer0 = self.layer0_1x1(layer0)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer0], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up0(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    x = torch.cat([x, x_original], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_original_size2(x)

    out = self.conv_last(x)

    return out
```

for this command

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = ResNetUNet()
model = model.to(device)

# check keras-like model summary using torchsummary
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=(3, 600, 900))
```

it throws the error:

```
     54     x = self.upsample(layer4)
     55     layer3 = self.layer3_1x1(layer3)
---> 56     x = torch.cat([x, layer3], dim=1)
     57     x = self.conv_up3(x)
     58 

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 3. Got 57 and 58
```

Not sure what to do here. Could someone help me how to solve this?

Comment: I tried reproducing your error but you did not define convrelu in this piece of code. So, I will just try to help you with comments what to do. Could you try printing shape of x and layer3 before line 56?

Comment: add a reproducible code snippet, for example, what's convrelu?

Comment: @unsure_automata Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You just need to match tensor shapes before torch.cat.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import models
import torch.nn.functional as F

def match_shapes(x, y):

    if x.shape[-2:] != y.shape[-2:]:
        x = F.interpolate(x, y.shape[-2:], mode='nearest')

    return x

def convrelu(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding):
  return nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding=padding),
      nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
  )

class ResNetUNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_class=1):
    super().__init__()

    self.base_model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    self.base_layers = list(self.base_model.children())

    self.layer0 = nn.Sequential(*self.base_layers[:3]) # size=(N, 64, x.H/2, x.W/2)
    self.layer0_1x1 = convrelu(64, 64, 1, 0)
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(*self.base_layers[3:5]) # size=(N, 64, x.H/4, x.W/4)
    self.layer1_1x1 = convrelu(64, 64, 1, 0)
    self.layer2 = self.base_layers[5]  # size=(N, 128, x.H/8, x.W/8)
    self.layer2_1x1 = convrelu(128, 128, 1, 0)
    self.layer3 = self.base_layers[6]  # size=(N, 256, x.H/16, x.W/16)
    self.layer3_1x1 = convrelu(256, 256, 1, 0)
    self.layer4 = self.base_layers[7]  # size=(N, 512, x.H/32, x.W/32)
    self.layer4_1x1 = convrelu(512, 512, 1, 0)

    self.upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)

    self.conv_up3 = convrelu(256 + 512, 512, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up2 = convrelu(128 + 512, 256, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up1 = convrelu(64 + 256, 256, 3, 1)
    self.conv_up0 = convrelu(64 + 256, 128, 3, 1)

    self.conv_original_size0 = convrelu(3, 64, 3, 1)
    self.conv_original_size1 = convrelu(64, 64, 3, 1)
    self.conv_original_size2 = convrelu(64 + 128, 64, 3, 1)

    self.conv_last = nn.Conv2d(64, n_class, 1)

  def forward(self, input):
    x_original = self.conv_original_size0(input)
    x_original = self.conv_original_size1(x_original)

    layer0 = self.layer0(input)
    layer1 = self.layer1(layer0)
    layer2 = self.layer2(layer1)
    layer3 = self.layer3(layer2)
    layer4 = self.layer4(layer3)

    layer4 = self.layer4_1x1(layer4)
    x = self.upsample(layer4)
    layer3 = self.layer3_1x1(layer3)
    x = match_shapes(x, layer3)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer3], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up3(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer2 = self.layer2_1x1(layer2)
    x = match_shapes(x, layer2)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer2], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up2(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer1 = self.layer1_1x1(layer1)
    x = match_shapes(x, layer1)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer1], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up1(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    layer0 = self.layer0_1x1(layer0)
    x = torch.cat([x, layer0], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_up0(x)

    x = self.upsample(x)
    x = torch.cat([x, x_original], dim=1)
    x = self.conv_original_size2(x)

    out = self.conv_last(x)

    return out

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = ResNetUNet()
model = model.to(device)

# check keras-like model summary using torchsummary
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=(3, 600, 900))
```